# document.getElementsByClassName('query'); to appended items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am defining:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('query');
```

That works with the first element as we already have it on page:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control query" placeholder="Enter location">
```

But then I am adding an `input` with `class query` via `append()`, therefore when I do:

```
$("body").on("click", ".addLocation", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".locationAdd").append('<input type="text" class="form-control query" placeholder="Enter location"><button type="button" class="addLocation btn btn-danger margin-top-20">Add location</button><hr>');
});
```

And in this case the `var inputs` isn't recognizing the new `appended element`

Comment: Are you defining `inputs` before you append the new element?

Comment: @MattL. yes I am, because at the start we have `<input type="text" class="form-control query" placeholder="Enter location">` on page

Comment: When you call `document.getElementsByClassName` it only gets the elements in the DOM at the time of the call

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I know why it isn't working, and yes it is because of what you've just said, I am looking for an example solution tho

Comment: Exactly. It is retaining the value from when it was run. If you change something, it won't magically update itself.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn and Matt Nope, [`gEBCN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) returns a live collection, that should be automatically updates.

Comment: @rob.m Move the `var inputs` line to somewheres where it gets called every time you update the DOM? Be sure to not bring the `var` keyword with you. Don't want to keep re-creating a variable named var.

Comment: @rob.m a solution for what though?  All you've said is that the variable doesn't include the new element.  Fixing that is as simple as updating that variable any time a new one is created.

Comment: @Teemu That is good to know! I didn't know that

Comment: I provided my own solution, maybe not the best but works. Also @Anthony provided his own

Comment: oh here we go, a down vote. Thank you very much

Comment: @rob.m I [can't reproduce your problem](https://jsfiddle.net/uvagocjL/) ..?

Comment: @rob.m If you're getting the inputs after the appending, all should work fine: https://jsbin.com/qufuvulise/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: @DavidHorák yeah basically you did what I did and provided with my own answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51108321/1018804

Comment: @Teemu ok must have been gmaps then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it, basically placed everything inside a function, call it at the start and re-call it each time I add a new element. The following is the full code on my page, what I am adding is a new input field to add a new location, therefore I need to re-run the gmap code:

```js
setLocInput();
function setLocInput() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('query');
  var autocompletes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i]);
    autocomplete.inputId = inputs[i].id;
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillIn);
    autocompletes.push(autocomplete);
  }
  var locationsArray = [];
  function fillIn() {
    var place = this.getPlace();
    var filtered_array = place.address_components.filter(function(address_component){
      return address_component.types.includes("country");
    }); 
    var country = filtered_array.length ? filtered_array[0].long_name: "";
    locationsArray.push(country);
    $("#usp-custom-8").attr("value", locationsArray);
    $("#usp-custom-8").attr("data-location", locationsArray);
  }
}
$("body").on("click", ".addLocation", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".locationAdd").append('<input type="text" class="form-control query" placeholder="Enter location"><button type="button" class="addLocation btn btn-danger margin-top-20">Add location</button><hr>');
  setLocInput();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=getRelevantGoogleReviews"></script>

 <input type="text" class="form-control query">
```

Comment: You didn't mention the use of gmap in your question. that won't automatically update just from an input being added to the DOM. So you would always need to run the `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(theNewInputElement)` etc code for a new element

Comment: @PatrickEvans regardless of gmaps, it wasn't recognising `var inputs` and that is because the append doesn't see that var

Comment: @PatrickEvans and nope, the code in this answer works fine and the `js` I am using for `gplaces`, is a general global code which works on any field with class `query`, so no need to run `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(theNewInputElement)`

Comment: I didn't say the code wouldn't work. I was saying your understanding of the problem was flawed. It isn't that something isn't recognizing `var inputs`, it is that you didn't update gmap with the new input. Meaning you don't have to go through the whole for loop, you just need to do the autocomplete steps for the new input

Comment: @PatrickEvans that's not correct, I didn't care about if was or not gmaps, even if I was doing `console.log(youAre);` wouldn't work since i declared a variable `var youAre = "Wrong";` outside the append

Comment: Yes it is correct. For an `HTMLCollection` it doesn't matter if you declared it outside the append, as it is a live object, as it has been repeatedly said, it automatically gets updated when the dom changes.

Comment: @PatrickEvans actually you're correct indeed, if I remove the gmaps bit then var inputs works